# Unable to hide PHP warnings

Tags: php

PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Oct 29 2014 12:16:30):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';
$db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
```

——————————

output:

**Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): Headers and client library minor version
mismatch. Headers:50540 Library:50621 in…**

——————————

Disclaimer: I'm not used to hide errors and warnings but this warning is driving me crazy on Ubuntu 12.04. Since my plan is to move soon the server to Ubuntu 14, I decided to ignore it in the meanwhile. But, of course, the android app I'm doing doesn't appreciate so much this warning as the JSON parser fails so I'm locked. What can I do ?

I've tried also "error_reporting(0)" and many many other suggestions found on docs and sites.

Comment: Could db_config.php be enabling errors?

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHHHHH! I have to sleep more !!! was too easy to be seen :)

Comment: thanks a lot, unbelievable how much time I've lost

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't remove warnings system-wide to hide one warning. You should either fix it or hide that particular issue.

You can do something like this:

```
function getDB()
{
    return new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
}

$db = @getDB();
```

The '@' operator ensures that errors or warnings within the function are ignored.

Though obviously the best approach would be to fix the error in question.

Comment: I usually suggest against the `@` operator.  It's usually better to try to *fix* the issue.

Comment: Yeah, though one @ is better than removing all warnings altogether.